# PDF Image to DOC or another editable format

Tags: r

I have a bunch of PDF files, which are images, and I'd like to convert them into doc, so I could realize language processing and extract photos from it.

(I could just use pdf to doc site, but once I have more than a hundred files...)
I considered AI Builder, from Microsoft, but it doesn't extract images, just texts/numbers/dates

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: You can extract text and images from PDFs with (for example) ImageMagick without the need for the R programming language or another interim format such as doc/docx. With R, you could use the `magick` package to help facilitate that, especially useful if you're planning on doing your language processing in R.